# Object.create(parent) vs Object.create(parent.prototype)

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

My question is about inheritance in javascript. So when you have

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype)
```

you are setting the prototype of the child class to a copy of the parent class prototype. If you check in the console the `__proto__` property of the child class shows directly `__proto__: parent`. So far so good. But when you make inheritance like that -

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent)
```

the `__proto__` property of child shows `__proto__: function parent()` and this function has property prototype which has key-value `prototype: parent`. The instances of both act the same. Obviously the compiler should take only 1 step more to find the functions in the prototype. There is some kind of difference but is it so significant so `Object.create(parent.prototype)` is preferred. Can anyone explain this in simple terms?

Comment: The first is just wrong.

Comment: Inheritance is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I know it is wrong but it works. Can anyone tell why it is wrong?

Comment: "*The instances of both act the same.*" - no they don't. Try to invoke a method that is inherited from `Parent.prototype`.

Comment: Well in my demo the parent had only some "private" properties. I guess you cant call a function as property of the child istance when you make Object.create(parent) without prototype?

Answer (score 2):

One of the most confusing pitfalls in javascript is that `.prototype` and "prototype" are different things. In your example, properties of the first object are resolved via `parent.prototype`, while the second uses "parent's prototype" aka `parent.__proto__`. Consider:

```
function parent() {};

var a = Object.create(parent.prototype); 
var b = Object.create(parent);
```

This is the inheritance diagram for this code:

[image]

As you can see, prototype chains for `a` and `b` are quite different.

Comment: Could you please use `[[prototype]]` instead of `__proto__`? The latter is an accessor property inherited from `Object.prototype`, the former is the internal slot that you mean.

Comment: It might help if you'd name the large objects "Function.prototype" and "Object.prototype". Btw, what diagram editor is that?

Comment: Verry nice diagram. I was refferening to inheritance like function a(){}, then a.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype), but I am guessing you get the same thing - a new copy of the object? So in your example you are making an object AKA reference to the prototype or to the direct function, in my case I am saying "property a.prototype" be a reference to that parent.prototype. Another question what is this at the top right corner? Some kind of a function wrapper?

Comment: @Danielpetrov: could you update your question with some example code, because I don't really understand...

Comment: @Danielpetrov: I didn't draw this diagram, it's generated by the browser, so this is how the browser sees your objects.